# Problem with clicking on favorite item in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I’m trying to create rss news feeding app using Volley library/JSON with on the base of RecyclerView, where each row contains title, pubdate, description and link to the Article.

This app should allow to create a list of favorite articles(DB).

When I run the app with placeholder info instead of real internet content, everything works OK.

But when I run it with internet connection  and click on the “favorite ” button(heart), the following error appears: 
[loaded info from internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDvDe.jpg)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq37X.png)
Below is the part of the related code with highlighted line and debug log:

```
public BbsNewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
    super(itemView);
    titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    pubDateTextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPubDate);
    descriptionTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    linkTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.link);
    favBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favBtn);
    //add to favorites
    favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            ArticleItem articleItem = articleItems.get(position);
            if (articleItem.getFavStatus().equals("0")) {
                articleItem.setFavStatus("1");
                favDB.insertIntoTheDatabase(articleItem.getTitle(),
                    articleItem.getPubDate(),
                    articleItem.getDescription(),
                    articleItem.getWebUrl(),
                    articleItem.getKey_id(),
                    articleItem.getFavStatus());
                favBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_color);
            } else {
                articleItem.setFavStatus("0");
                favDB.remove_fav(articleItem.getKey_id());
                favBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Error Log:

```
04/06 16:29:34: Launching 'app' on Nexus 4 API 23.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.favoritelist/com.example.favoritelist.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.favoritelist.test | com.example.favoritelist
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.favoritelist.test | com.example.favoritelist
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.favoritelist.test | com.example.favoritelist
Connecting to com.example.favoritelist
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8628', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1495)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.favoritelist-2/lib/x86
W/FirebaseApp: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3fefd40, tid 6001
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa1cff240, tid 6040
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae6b45c0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae6b45c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xb2a145c0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae6b45c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xb2a145c0)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.favoritelist, PID: 6001
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.favoritelist.ArticleAdapter$BbsNewsViewHolder$1.onClick(ArticleAdapter.java:89)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6001 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8628', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Probably articleItem.getFavStatus() is null.  You can see NullPointerException

Comment: thanks. can you please give more details if possible on this? yes, it refers to articleItem.getFavStatus(), but I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, you got `NullPointException` with the following log:

> `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

So, the cause of this exception that you call `.equals()` method on a `String` object. Looking back into your code; you used `.equals()` only once in `articleItem.getFavStatus().equals("0")`.

So, obviously your `articleItem.getFavStatus()` is a null value and you are trying to compare it to "0". So, you need to check why it returns null, also you can wrap this part of code into a `try` block, or put a break point at this statement to examine it.

hope that help you out.